# Why are we using Square Brackets in python to access MIMEMultipart() components like ['From'], ['To'] for sending email using python?

Tags: python, list, smtplib, mimemultipart

In a python code, which is sending an email using "smtplib" and "MIMEMultipart" libraries,

I got a doubt on, why we are using "square brackets" for ['From'], ['To'] and ['Subject'] when referring to "MIMEMultipart ()". Could any anyone explain on this part ?

**Below is the code snipet, observe the commenting lines :**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
mail_content = '''Hello,This is a test mail.'''
sender_address = 'xyz710@gmail.com'
sender_pass = 'wesqabfucxfqcg'
receiver_address = 'abcd12@gmail.com'

#Setup the MIME
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address #  ** why are we using square bracket [] here ?? **
message['To'] = receiver_address # ** why are we using square bracket [] here ?? **
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'
# **why are we using square bracket [] here ?? **

message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
attach_file_name = 'TP_python_prev.pdf'
attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb') # Open the file as binary mode
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream')
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload) #encode the attachment
payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=attach_file_name)
message.attach(payload)
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

Comment: Why not? It's the same way you set new values in a `dict`, and presumably the class involved here is a mapping of some sort, with a potentially large (unrestricted?) set keys, or ones which don't correspond to legal variable names, so they just let you set them directly in whatever order you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing; you're setting.

`MIMEMultipart` defines a magic method `__setitem__` which defines the syntax for `OBJECT[key] = value`

> The conceptual model provided by an `EmailMessage` object is that of an ordered **dictionary** of headers coupled with a payload that represents the RFC 5322 body of the message

Comment: Could you share the link regarding "MIMEMultipart defines a magic method __setitem__" ?
I shall try to read and understand it .

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.__setitem__